# how to write a value to a attribute of html element in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have written a code for writing a value to a html element attribute and the input button to which I have to write the value of subb is shown below :

```js
$(".namequip").click(function(){

  var cartno = 22;
  //var onesOnly = cartno % 10;
  var cartno = parseInt(cartno%10);
  var initialno = $('.namequip').attr("data-cartno");
  if(initialno == ""){
    var initialno = 0;
  }

  alert(cartno);
  alert(initialno);

  var subb = parseInt(cartno) - parseInt(initialno);
  alert(subb);

  $("button#equp").find('.namequip').attr('data-cartno',subb);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="equpn" class="namequip btn btn-primary prev-step"  data-fname="" data-cartno="" data-fid="" data-name="" data-id="">
  Next Person
</button>
```

But the value of subb cannot be written into the button, why is it like that ?

Comment: What does `getname()` look like? As it is also called on button click?

Comment: getname() is for another purpose..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything's ok just change

```
$("button#equp").find('.namequip').attr('data-cartno',subb);
```

To

```
$(this).attr('data-cartno',subb);
```

Or

```
$(this).data('cartno',subb);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using data attribute you can use the following to set as data attribute value,

```
$("button#equp").find('.namequip').data('cartno',subb);
```

and for get the value simply use the following

```
$("button#equp").find('.namequip').data('cartno');
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake:
Your button id is `equpn` and in your jquery code you are doing this `button#equp`.
There is a mistake that is why you are not getting the answer. Please change the code of your button like this.

```
$("button#equpn").find('.namequip').attr('data-cartno',subb);
 });
```

**Update:**

```
$("#equpn").attr('data-cartno',subb);
```